# "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/plain." error

Tags: bug, live-refresh

The Safari's Web Inspector reports the following error, when I am visiting a page here on meta.

[image: screenshot]

The string that appears before the error message is the following one:

> pixel;r=109085478;a=p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc;fpan=0;fpa=P0-1055317726-1325192096920;ns=0;ce=1;je=1;sr=1600x900x24;enc=n;dst=1;et=1330812109285;tzo=-60;ref=http%3A%2F%2Fdrupal.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F24314%2Fi-get-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-this-page-when-i-try-to-load-a-view-wit;url=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F124423%2Fhow-to-search-for-a-user-name-as-a-advanced-super-ninja-search-option%23comment333302_124423;ogl=

The following is the information WebInspector reports about the open WebSockets.

[image: screenshot]

I am not able to see the message about new activity other users see. Could this error be the cause?

I am using Safari 5.1.3 on Mac OS X 10.7.3.

Comment: **WOW**, that was super random. I instinctively flagged this as off-topic, lol.

Comment: Nah, this is just contentless request that QuantServe uses to get all up n ur interwebz. The response doesn't include a content type, so since it falls back to `text/plain` and Safari was expecting an image, it gets upset.

Comment: Whoops, got my WebKit browsers confused. ;)