# Safari is not showing notifications of updated answers

Tags: bug, edits, live-refresh, safari, updating-questions

On Chrome or Firefox, when you are viewing a question and something has been modified, or a new answer was submitted, or other changes to what you are looking at, normally there is a prompt like

> "an edit has been made to this post; click to load".

However on Safari, I see no such notification, and just have to reload to see if anything has changed.

Comment: Version? OS? ...

Comment: It depends on Websockets so try http://websocketstest.com as well.

Comment: @Yannis  Safari Version 6.0.5. On OSX Version 10.8.5

Comment: @StevenV Everything checks out on the websockets test for my Safari browser.

Comment: Check the Web Inspector, this might be a dupe of [this report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124442/152859) (that was never fixed)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Can you point me to a website on how to use the web inspector like that post does?  I have been trying it, but have yet to figure it out, or find one myself, but have yet find anything helpful.

Comment: @Xantham according to [this](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/safari/developer-tools.html): "To access these tools, enable the Develop menu in Safari’s Advanced preferences". Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I was able to get that far, but inside it, I could not find how to look at websockets like the second image on the post you linked.  I found [this](http://blog.kaazing.com/2012/02/08/how-to-tell-if-your-websocket-connection-is-native-or-emulated/), but it was apparently a different version of Safari, so my interface does not look the same as what they say to find the web sockets information.